# How do I insert spacing/padding in XSL-FO generated PDF for fields without any value?

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have the following XML:

```
<sample>
    <value1>This is one</value1>
    <value2>Number two</value2>
    <value4>Last value</value4>
</sample>
```

Using Apache FOP/XSL-FO I would like a PDF looking similar to this:

```
Value 1: This is one Value 2: Number two
Value 3:                 Value 4: Last value
```

Notice the spacing/padding between "Value 3:" and "Value 4:".

The following transformation gives my the result I want. But it seems overly complicated (and might not perform very well for a real-life PDF with many values).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:template match="sample">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-layout">
                    <fo:region-body margin="10mm" region-name="body"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page-layout">
                <fo:flow flow-name="body">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:variable name="pad">                            
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="value1">5</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>25</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <fo:inline padding-right="{$pad}mm">Value 1: <xsl:value-of select="value1"/></fo:inline>
                        Value 2: <xsl:value-of select="value2"/>
                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:variable name="pad">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="value3">5</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>25</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <fo:inline padding-right="{$pad}mm">Value 3: <xsl:value-of select="value3"/></fo:inline>
                        Value 4: <xsl:value-of select="value4"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a simpler/better way to implement this?

**Update:**

I refactored the above into a template "field":

```
<xsl:template name="field">
    <xsl:param name="txt"/>
    <xsl:param name="val"/>
    <xsl:param name="pad"/>
    <xsl:variable name="p">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$val">5</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$pad"><xsl:value-of select="$pad"/></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>25</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <fo:inline padding-right="{$p}mm"><xsl:value-of select="$txt"/>:</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-with-previous="always" padding-right="5mm" font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="$val"/></fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

Which can be used like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="field">
    <xsl:with-param name="txt">Value 1</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="val"><xsl:value-of select="sample/value1"/></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

The template takes a third optional parameter, pad. If specified its value will be used as padding.

David's template (see accepted answer) uses a simpler if-contruct where the padding-right attribute is overwritten if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this presumably isn't being executed in a browser is there any reason not to use xslt2 (which would make it rather nicer) since you are using java anyway the free saxon 9 implementation would work well here.

But here's an XSLT 1 version refactored a bit.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:template match="sample">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-layout">
                    <fo:region-body margin="10mm" region-name="body"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page-layout">
                <fo:flow flow-name="body">
         <xsl:call-template name="twoval">
          <xsl:with-param name="a" select="value1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="ahead" select="'Value 1'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="b" select="value2"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="bhead" select="'Value 2'"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
         <xsl:call-template name="twoval">
          <xsl:with-param name="a" select="value3"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="ahead" select="'Value 3'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="b" select="value4"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="bhead" select="'Value 4'"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="twoval">
<xsl:param name="a"/>
<xsl:param name="ahead"/>
<xsl:param name="b"/>
<xsl:param name="bhead"/>
<fo:block>
 <fo:inline padding-right="25mm">
  <xsl:if test="$a"><xsl:attribute name="padding-right">5mm</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="$ahead"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$a"/>
 </fo:inline>
 <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="$bhead"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="$b"/>
</fo:block>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I ended up with, but I used a xls:choose to set a padding variable. Just overriding the attribute when needed is more elegant.